# MySQL setup on Ubuntu 18 on Google Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have just setup a VM instance on Google Cloud and want to run LAMP.The system i use is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

When installing MySQL server and PHPmyadmin I dont get a question to set password (usaly do on other setups like DigitalOcean).

I run command: mysql_secure_installation and set a password.

When try login on PHPmyadmin i get:

```
1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

and

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Since i dont use a password when login to putty but a keyfile, i guess no password is set as default?

How would i get remote access to PHPmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

I'm migrating from a traditional, stand alone LAMP box using Ubuntu to GCP, and I had this issue, which drove me insane for a few hours.

Each time I would use mysql -u root -p and provide what I know was the proper credentials, always access denied.

To fix this, I simply had to put SUDO in front of the command, which is a bit counterintuitive to what I was used to. Using sudo is the only way I could finally log in on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 5.7+, that means for you, that root login is not possible to connect to phpmyadmin.

1. Connect to MySQL:
   sudo mysql --user=root mysql
2. Create user for phpmyadmin:
   CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;